# "Ann loves Mary but not Kate."= "Ann loves Mary but Kate does not."?

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis

What is the probability of "***Ann loves Mary but not Kate***." being interpreted as "***Ann loves Mary but Kate does not.***" ? Does prosody change anything here?

Comment: Ann juggles oranges but not Kate.

Comment: We are always permitted to use context to understand. But "Ann loves Mary but not Kate" is short for *... but does not love Kate*. It is unlikely to be short for *... but **not Kate** loves Mary.*

Answer (score 4):

Absent any context, "Ann loves Mary but not Kate" is very likely to be interpreted to mean "Ann loves Mary but Ann does not love Kate". This is partly because "but not Kate", coming immediately after "Mary", attaches more readily there, and partly because "Ann loves Mary but Kate does not" is available to express the other meaning clearly and concisely.

But the "Kate does not" meaning is not impossible, and indeed prosody can alter the likelihood of which meaning is understood: reading it as "*Ann* loves Mary, but not *Kate*" indicates to the listener that the emphasised names are the ones contrasted.

Comment: *Ann loves Mary but not Kate. No, not Kate, she can't stand Mary.* Yeah, prosody (and the right tone of voice) can twist sentences right around.